# SQL count with left join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, count

i want to get data from 2 tables using left join, here's my table

**First table (folder)**

| number | date |
| --- | --- |
| 123/123 | 2021-08-14 |
| 321/321 | 2021-08-15 |
| 456/456 | 2021-08-15 |
| 098/098 | 2021-08-16 |
| 654/654 | 2021-08-17 |

**second table (certificate)**

| code | folder_number |
| --- | --- |
| asd1 | 123/123 |
| asd2 | 123/123 |
| asd3 | 123/123 |
| asd4 | 123/123 |
| asd5 | 123/123 |
| qwe1 | 321/321 |
| qwe2 | 321/321 |
| qwe3 | 321/321 |
| zxc1 | 456/456 |
| zxc2 | 456/456 |
| zxc3 | 456/456 |
| rty1 | 098/098 |
| fgh1 | 654/654 |

i only use `date` column from `folder` table, i want to count all data by `date` from `folder` table and left join `certificate` table that also count all `code` that connected/related to `number` column from `folder` table, here's my code

```
SELECT b.date, COUNT(c.code) as code, COUNT(b.date) as datecount
                FROM folder b
                INNER JOIN certificate c
                    ON c.folder_number = b.number
            GROUP BY b.date
            ORDER BY b.date
```

my expectation for that code:

| date | code | datecount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-14 | 5 | 1 |
| 2021-08-15 | 6 | 2 |
| 2021-08-16 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-08-17 | 1 | 1 |

but, here's what i get when use that code:

| date | code | datecount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-14 | 5 | 5 |
| 2021-08-15 | 6 | 6 |
| 2021-08-16 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-08-17 | 1 | 1 |

how to fix it? i also try using `inner join` but the result is same

Thanks, sorry for my bad english btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `COUNT(b.date)` you should count the distinct number of `number`:

```
SELECT b.date, 
       COUNT(c.code) as code, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT b.number) as datecount
FROM folder b INNER JOIN certificate c
ON c.folder_number = b.number
GROUP BY b.date
ORDER BY b.date;
```

If there are `number`s in `folder` that may have no match in `certificate` then you should use a `LEFT` join.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3e947756444c828619e33bdc881ed5c5).